# How to make objects fadeIn one after the next using ajax/json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get my div holding the json data to animate one after another. right now they pretty much come in all at the same time.
kind of like a staggered animation. Any help would be great, thank you.

my script

```
     ajax: function(){
        $.ajax('projects.json', {
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                var count = 0;
                for(var i=0;i<result.projectName.length;i++){
                    count++;
                    result.projectName[i].ID = count;
                    var el = $("<li class='item'><h1>"+
                        result.projectName[i].name+"</h1><div><img src='"+
                        result.projectName[i].url+"' alt='"+result.projectName[i].name+"'></div><div>"+
                        result.projectName[i].color+"</div><div>"+
                        result.projectName[i].ID+"</div></li>");
                        intro.find('ul').append(el).fadeIn();
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("Error ajax not working"+error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my json

```
{
"projectName": [{
        "name": "shortSleeve",
        "url": "/../images/frog.jpg",
        "color": "blue",
        "ID": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "slongSleeve",
        "url": "images/frog.jpg",
        "color": "red",
        "ID": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "turtleSleeve",
        "url": "images/frog.jpg",
        "color": "purple",
        "ID": ""
    }]


  }
```

Comment: Try adding `.delay()` to `intro.find('ul').append(el).fadeIn();` like so: `intro.find('ul').append(el).fadeIn().delay(500);`.

Comment: That didn't work. i think it has to be associated to the .animate method to work. i could be wrong. thanks

Comment: True, try `intro.find('ul').append(el).hide().fadeIn().delay(500);`

Comment: I made a jasfiddle , i dont know how to get it to work with the json call. http://jsfiddle.net/nka1esrw/

Comment: I figured it out and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you start the animation before you get the data. You need to set a delay on the `li` elements you are adding.

```
for(var i=0;i<result.projectName.length;i++){
                    count++;
                    result.projectName[i].ID = count;
                    var el = $("<li class='item'><h1>"+
                        result.projectName[i].name+"</h1><div><img src='"+
                        result.projectName[i].url+"' alt='"+result.projectName[i].name+"'></div><div>"+
                        result.projectName[i].color+"</div><div>"+
                        result.projectName[i].ID+"</div></li>").hide(); //hide it before appending it
                        intro.find('ul').append(el.delay(1500 + (count*300)).fadeIn()); //now add a delay that gets incrementally higher
                }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/nka1esrw/1/)

Comment: That did the job, thank you so much. I have been racking my brain on that one for more hours than i needed to haha.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to define timeout function and then just use result.projectName.shift() to get current element and append it to ul with fadein effect, then re-run the timeout until result.projectName length is 0.

Or you could also add all elements to ul in your for loop as hidden

```
 el.appendTo(intro.find('ul')).hide();
```

And then after for loop you can run fadeIn something like

```
var _Fadein = function()
{
    if ($('li:hidden', intro.find('ul')).filter(':first').is('*'))
    {
        $('li:hidden', intro.find('ul')).filter(':first').fadeIn(1000, _Fadein);
    }
};
_Fadein();
```

Comment: I think this `intro.find('ul').append(el).hide();` will hide the `ul` element instead of the `li` elements.

Comment: @imtheman right you are el.appendTo(intro.find('ul')).hide() should work. Correcting my answer

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that each li element is assigned a different id (example: id="myLi2") on the for loop. Then, by using nextId variable, we keep track of the current li, which is used in the function fadeInNext() to find the next id, and then it calls fadeIn on that element.

Note we are using the complete call back parameter for the fadeIn method, we are passing fadeInNext, which will call the fadeInNext function when the fadeIn effect is completed.

```
//Use a variable to keep track of the current <li>
var nextId = 1;

//this function will call fadeIn on the next <li>, you can change 'slow' for an int (milliseconds)
function fadeInNext() {
    $('#myLi'+nextId).fadeIn('slow', fadeInNext);
    nextId++;
}

ajax: function(){
    $.ajax('projects.json', {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            var count = 0;
            for(var i=0;i<result.projectName.length;i++){
                count++;
                result.projectName[i].ID = count;
                var el = $("<li id='myLi"+i+"' style='display:none;' class='item'><h1>"+ //added an id and style to hide it, you can put that in css
                    result.projectName[i].name+"</h1><div><img src='"+
                    result.projectName[i].url+"' alt='"+result.projectName[i].name+"'></div><div>"+
                    result.projectName[i].color+"</div><div>"+
                    result.projectName[i].ID+"</div></li>");
                    intro.find('ul').append(el); //Wait dont call fadeIn here
            }

            //Call fadeIn on first <li>, the second parameter will call fadeInNext when fadeIn is completed
            $('#myLi0').fadeIn('slow', fadeInNext);
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert("Error ajax not working"+error);
        }
    });
}
```